# Laravel и laracasts/integrated пакет

Tags: laravel

Установил https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated/wiki/Installation-and-Setup
запускаю phpunit
Fatal error: Access level to Laracasts\Integrated\Extensions\Traits\LaravelTestCase::get() must be public (as in class Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase) in E:\OpenServer\domains\laraveltest.loc\vendor\laracasts\integrated\src\Extensions\Laravel.php on line 9

Comment: А версия пакета ты смотрел совпадает Laravel и того пакета что ты ставишь ? судя по всему должен быть public метод  get(), который что то реализовывает, причем он должен быть public